# Listen to updates on certain query with array fields on Cloud Firestore (Android)

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

The picture below shows the data structure for the simple chat application. A channel is created between two users when they want to communicate. Member string array field lists the usernames.

I want to notify the user when any of the channels of logged in user receive a message. Not sure how this can be done.

I tried below query with no success. Any ideas?

```
    listenerRegistration2 =
            firebaseFirestore.collection(COLLECTION_CHANNELS)
                    .whereEqualTo("members.0", username)
                    .addSnapshotListener((queryDocumentSnapshots, e) -> {
                        Log.d("myApp", "queryDocumentSnapshots = ");
                    });
```

[image]

Comment: How do you want to notify the user?

Comment: If you want to send a notification, note that I have exaplained in one of my **[tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLn2n4GESV0AmXOWOam729bC47v0d0Ohee)** step by step, how you can send **[notifications](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6RzB4HXzQyA&t=3s&list=PLn2n4GESV0AmXOWOam729bC47v0d0Ohee&index=17)** to specific users using Cloud Firestore and Node.js.

Comment: I am planing to use above code and listen on background service and then notify the user when listener call back is executed.  The only problem I am facing is how to write a query with the current data model.

Comment: I understand now. I'll write you an answer right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit: September 12, 2018**

Starting with `August 28, 2018`, now it's possible to update array members. More informations **[here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array)**.

---

As in the official documentation regarding [arrays](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/arrays):

> Although Cloud Firestore can store arrays, **`it does not support`** querying array members or updating single array elements.

So unfortunately you cannot achieve this using arrays. If you only want to get the entire `memebers` array, just use a `get()` call and then only to iterate over a `Map` like this:

```
Map<String, Object> map = documentSnapshot.getData();
for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    if (entry.getKey().equals("memebers")) {
        Log.d("TAG", entry.getValue().toString());
    }
}
```

But note, even if `memebers` object is stored in the database as an array, `entry.getValue()` returns an `ArrayList`, not an `array`.

There is also an workaround here, that can help you achieve this but you need to change the `memebers` array property to a `map`. So a better approach will be if you consider this alternative database structure, where each memeber is the key in a map and all values are true:

```
memebers: {
    "sister12": true,
    "wow": true
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, how would you write a query to get/listen new messages in all channels related to a specific user /member. If current model does not support it what would be the best model and how would the query look like.

Comment: In this case, you should consider augmenting your data structure to allow a reverse lookup and for that I recommend you see one of my **[tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLn2n4GESV0AmXOWOam729bC47v0d0Ohee)** in which the shoppings lists are more likely chat rooms (channels), right?

Comment: In particular I recommend you see this episode [Database Structure](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=idywm80Qbvc&t=15s&list=PLn2n4GESV0AmXOWOam729bC47v0d0Ohee&index=4).