# How to update array elements in Firestore with Android?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51605958/listen-to-updates-on-certain-query-with-array-fields-on-cloud-firestore-android) and this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51202300/how-to-add-update-remove-array-elements-in-firebase-firestore-android-using-hash) of the same guy saying that you cannot update array elements.

I also read a recent [article](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2018/08/better-arrays-in-cloud-firestore.html), where is says that this can be done somehow with `arrayUnion` or something like that but I cannot get any informations on stackoverflow either in the docs.

Is there any way I can solve this? Thanks!

Comment: Check this link :  
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array

[Update elements in an array]

If your document contains an array field, you can use arrayUnion() and arrayRemove() to add and remove elements. arrayUnion() adds elements to an array but only elements not already present. arrayRemove() removes all instances of each given element.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, even thought providing links into questions is good to explain the issue you are facing, it is still recommended for you to give some more background and explanation about the issue you are trying to resolve.

Comment: Hmm, already having answer for your question in this link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46757614/how-to-update-an-array-of-objects-with-firestore/

Comment: @AshishDas Thanks but I'm looking for Android, that answer provides a solution in Javascript and do not understand.

Comment: @smn.tino I need to know if this is possible, so I can use this feature in my project or not and I understand is possible. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Actually, the "guy" who wrote those answers it's me :) At that time, there wasn't a way in which you could update array elements. It was possible only to store arrays but **not** to update array members.

Now, when updating a document, you can pass as the second argument to the `update()` method:

```
FieldValue.arrayUnion("newArrayValue")
```

You can find more informations in the official documentation regarding [update elements in an array](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array).

> If your document contains an array field, you can use arrayUnion() and arrayRemove() to add and remove elements. arrayUnion() adds elements to an array but only elements not already present. arrayRemove() removes all instances of each given element.

P.S. I will also update those answers.

Comment: it is possible to update single item from array ?

Comment: @AKASHWANGALWAR Maybe you're looking for [this approach](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-update-an-array-of-objects-in-firestore-cdb611a56073), right?

Answer (score 0):

Try using  FieldValue.arrayUnion(comment_full) instead of passing comment_full                 FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("posts").document("$postid").update("comments",FieldValue.arrayUnion(comment_full))

Comment: Answer doesn't bring any value, as it's basically a copy of accepted answer.